# How do you signal an error from within an expandable function?

Tags: errors, latex3, expl3, terminal-output

I would like to do some error checking from within an expandable function.  But my attempts at signalling an error are not processed correctly, but rather returned to the input stream---contrary to my expectations.

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-eucl}
\psset{unit=0.25cm}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\msg_new:nnnn {testing}{testing}{illegal~property}{}
%% property list
\prop_new:N \g__ace_all_properties_plist
%% setter
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__ace_set_property:nn #1#2
    {
        \prop_gput:Nnn \g__ace_all_properties_plist { #1 } { #2 }
    }
%% getter
\cs_new:Npn \__ace_get_property:n #1
    {
        \prop_get:Nn \g__ace_all_properties_plist { #1 }
    }
%%--- User interface for settr and gettr
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\settr}{ m m }
    {
        \__ace_set_property:nn { #1 }{ #2 }
    }
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\gettr}{ m }
    {
        \prop_if_in:NnTF \g__ace_all_properties_plist { #1 }
            {
                \__ace_get_property:n { #1 }
            }
            {
                %% this next line does not get executed
                %% even when there #1 is not in the list
                %<var 1>%\msg_info_text:n { #1 ~ is ~ not ~ defined }
                \msg_fatal_text:n { testing}
            }

    }        
\ExplSyntaxOff
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\settr{displacement}{10}%

This picture gets processed correctly\par
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(10,10)
    \pstGeonode[PointName=default,PointSymbol=default,PosAngle=0](0,0){A}(0,1){B}
    \pstTranslation[DistCoef=\gettr{displacement}]{A}{B}{A}[C]
\end{pspicture}

\vspace{1cm}

No error signaled here $\rightarrow$
\gettr{unknownproperty}

\vspace{1cm}

This picture should signal an error when commented line uncommented\par
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(10,10)
    \pstGeonode[PointName=default,PointSymbol=default,PosAngle=0](0,0){A}(0,1){B}
    %\pstTranslation[DistCoef=\gettr{unknown-property}]{A}{B}{A}[C]
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Initially, I thought this was an issue of calling a protect function `\msg_term:x` from within an expandable function.  But, my errors are not properly triggered even when using using `\mgs_fatal_text:n`.  This later approach is not really what I want.  But signalling an error in any way would be nice.

**EDIT**

Following @DavidCarlisle's suggestion, I tried replacing

```
\msg_fatal_text:n{ testing }
```

with

```
\ERROR
```

So, the compilation stops, but since the wrong type of error message is signaled, I can imagine wasting a lot of time looking for the wrong error.  So, instead of `\ERROR` I tried

```
\use:c { Attempting ~ to ~ call ~ undefined ~ property -> {#1} }
```

I figured at least with this, I'd get an error that made it clearer what the real issue was.
But this doesn't signal an error at all---contrary to my expectations.

Comment: `\use:c` is just `\csname ...\endcsname` hidden. This also doesn't trigger an error when the csname doesn't exist but defines it to be equal to `\relax`

Comment: @cgnieder, so how do I signal an error message that will better info me about what the real issue is?

Comment: (In fact that is a way to safely call a command that does nothing if it doesn't exist. E.g. `\csname phantomsection\endcsname` won't do harm if `hyperref` is not loaded.) How about an undefined `\undefinedproperty`?

Comment: The kernel has the internal functions `\__msg_kernel_expandable_error:nnn` and `\__msg_expandable_error:n` that don't have, at least for now, a "programmer's level" interface.

Comment: @egreg.  What does it mean to say there is not "programmer's level interface"?  If they're documented and arguments not marked as ":D", doesn't that mean I can use them?

Comment: @A.Ellett No: they start `__`, meaning that they are 'internal' (the kernel has some functions which are not restricted to one module but to the kernel in general). The reason here is that it's very rare to absolutely require an error in an expandable context.

Comment: `\__msg_expandable_error:n { #1~not~defined }` should be what you're looking for. However, functions whose name starts with `__` are not to be relied upon (they are private, in this case in the `msg` module). If use cases show useful, the kernel developers may provide a "public" version. I'm not sure that you really need such an error message.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you actually want to generate the error in an expansion only context such as a `\write` or a PS `\special` the usual way is just to use an undefined command such as `\ERROR` You can not trigger any other error from there (and LaTeX3 can't really change that).

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 ...ptingToCallUndefinedPropertyunknownproperty



\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-eucl}
\psset{unit=0.25cm}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\msg_new:nnnn {testing}{testing}{illegal~property}{}
%% property list
\prop_new:N \g__ace_all_properties_plist
%% setter
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__ace_set_property:nn #1#2
    {
        \prop_gput:Nnn \g__ace_all_properties_plist { #1 } { #2 }
    }
%% getter
\cs_new:Npn \__ace_get_property:n #1
    {
        \prop_get:Nn \g__ace_all_properties_plist { #1 }
    }
%%--- User interface for settr and gettr
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\settr}{ m m }
    {
        \__ace_set_property:nn { #1 }{ #2 }
    }
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\gettr}{ m }
    {
        \prop_if_in:NnTF \g__ace_all_properties_plist { #1 }
            {
                \__ace_get_property:n { #1 }
            }
            {
                %% this next line does not get executed
                %% even when there #1 is not in the list
                %<var 1>%\msg_info_text:n { #1 ~ is ~ not ~ defined }
\foo{ Attempting  To  Call  Undefined  Property  #1 }
            }

    }

\ExplSyntaxOff

{\catcode`\@=0
@catcode`\\=12
@gdef@foo#1{@scantokens{\#1}}}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\settr{displacement}{10}%

This picture gets processed correctly\par
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(10,10)
    \pstGeonode[PointName=default,PointSymbol=default,PosAngle=0](0,0){A}(0,1){B}
    \pstTranslation[DistCoef=\gettr{displacement}]{A}{B}{A}[C]
\end{pspicture}

\vspace{1cm}

No error signaled here $\rightarrow$
\gettr{unknownproperty}

\vspace{1cm}

This picture should signal an error when commented line uncommented\par
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(10,10)
    \pstGeonode[PointName=default,PointSymbol=default,PosAngle=0](0,0){A}(0,1){B}
    %\pstTranslation[DistCoef=\gettr{unknown-property}]{A}{B}{A}[C]
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

(AM) David's trick is interesting:

```
{
  \catcode`\|=0
  |catcode`\\=12
  |gdef|throwundefined#1{|scantokens{\#1}}
}
\throwundefined{x}
```

Comment: Following your suggestion, I've attempted modifying my code.  But, I'm still not getting what I want.  How is my modification (see edit above) not doing what you were suggesting?

Comment: you are nearly right: but `\csname  this is not defined\endscsname` _defines_ the new csname to be `\relax` so you can `\let` that to be `\undefined` before entering your expansion only code. This may mean you want a fixed command name not one using `#1` so you can globally have a useful undefined command name.

Comment: I added some code that makes a csname on the fly using scantokens (I leave you to translate to idiomatic L3:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: But I saw somewhere that you contributed to phrasing the idioms.

Comment: @AhmedMusa last century sometime...

Answer (score 0):

Translaton of @DavidCarlisle's clever slight of hand:

```
\cs_new:Npn \foo #1 
    {
        \tl_rescan:nn
            {  
                \char_set_catcode_escape:N \@
            }{
                @#1 
            }
    }
```

Comment: No: `\tl_rescan:nn` is not expandable.  There is no expandable wrapper for `\scantokens` in LaTeX3.